# Issue with Auto Layout on iOS 8 (code works perfectly on iOS 7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios8

I have an app that was built using `auto-layout` and everything still works as expected when I run it on my iOS 7 device, however when I run it on an iOS 8 device some of my constraints go a little wacky.

I actually experienced a similar issue in another app but it wasn't a big issue. Now, I'm starting to wonder if it is a bug in the iOS 8 SDK or if there is a new way of handling auto layout in iOS8 that I'm not aware of.

Here is my setup:
I have a `UIView` with a `UIImageView` embedded inside it. Both the view and the image view have constraints pinning their bottom, leading & trailing edges to their superviews with constant = 0.

The `UIView` also has its top edge pinned to its superview and I have an IBOutlet connected to the constraint in order to adjust it programatically.  The `UIImageView` has a fourth constraint fixing its height to the height of the device (in my case 568).

Here is the behavior I am expecting/achieving in iOS 7:
I am trying to shrink the height of the container view and cause the top of the image view to be cut off w/o the aspect ratio changing (sort of looks like you cropped the top of the image off)...this is why I have pinned the height of the image view and the bottom edge.

What actually happens in iOS8:
The container view shrinks as expected (it stays pinned to the sides & bottom & the height shrinks).  The `UIImageView` behaves as if it had a top space constraint with cosntant == 0.  Instead of cutting off the top of the image, the whole image shrinks down.  Since I have the image in `AspectFit` mode, the sides pinch in as well to keep the aspect ratio the same (but the imageView itself remains pinned to the leading, trailing & bottom edges as it should).

How I do it:
I have a notification that fires from another part of my code to adjust the top-space constraint hooked up to the IBOutlet. The method it calls is really quite simple:

```
- (void) setTopSpaceForContainerView:(NSNotification*) notif{
    containerView_TopSpace.constant = [[notif.userInfo objectForKey:kTopSpace] intValue];
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Anyone else have a similar experience? I'm trying to find a workaround, but iOS 8 just seems determined to shrink my image.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm having problems which may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987244/autolayout-problems-with-ios8-with-code-that-works-fine-on-ios7
My app was fine on iOS7 and messed up on iOS8.  I'm still digging on this one but no daylight yet.

Comment: Same boat here with scrollview : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047595/extra-top-white-space-since-ios-8-using-autolayout-and-scrollview   No answer yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is definitely an iOS 8 bug.  I was able to work around it by sending `setNeedsLayout` to the container view (the superview of the image view).

I see that you're sending `setNeedsLayout` to `self.view`.  If that code is in your view controller, then I guess `self.view` is not the container view.  Try sending `setNeedsLayout` to the container view directly.

[Demo project is here.](https://github.com/mayoff/ios-8-layout-bug)

[image]

Comment: It works! +1 more because this is backwards compatible for iOS 7 as well. Which makes me wonder, in iOS7 calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and `setNeedsLayout` on the root view automatically trickled down to all the subviews.  Now we need to call setNeedsLayout specifically on the views that have constraints changing...that seems like it could reduce unnecessary layout calculations and speed things up.  Should I have been doing it this way all along?

Comment: I don't think it trickled down in the way you think.  I think that in iOS 7, changing the constraint constant flagged the constrained views as needing layout (or triggered the constraint solver in some other way), and in iOS 8 it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense.  Sounds like it is time for many of us to go fix all of our `setNeedsLayout` calls to point to the views that have a changing constraint.

Comment: I'm really excited to try this on my problem and see if things sort out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987244/autolayout-problems-with-ios8-with-code-that-works-fine-on-ios7   If so, I'll be back to mark this puppie UP!

Comment: I've been thinking more about this.  In iOS6/7, I've had two levels of nested VC's and I've never called setNeedsUpdateConstraints nor setNeedsLayout.  The layouts have always, up until iOS8, just seemed to lay themselves out.  The only thing I've done was to wait for viewDidLayoutSubviews so I could do something that I couldn't do until I knew all the calculations were over.  So, is the difference that now we have to explicitly ask for updates?  Still a bit puzzled about all of this.

Comment: I believe it's a bug that iOS 8 doesn't run auto layout when you change a constraint constant.

Comment: @robmayoff Can you please put together a simple sample project that demonstrates this issue (e.g. works on 7 SDK, but not on 8 SDK) and then file a radar and share the radar #? As you suggest this seems to be a bug: https://twitter.com/mairwatching/status/516985359414992897

Comment: @smileyborg [Project is here.](https://github.com/mayoff/ios-8-layout-bug)  You file the radar.

Comment: @robmayoff Haha, sure. Thanks for the project, let me check it out and file.

Comment: Filed as rdar://18502293

Comment: Bravo for doing the radar, friends.  robmayoff, ultimately, your issue and mine do not seem to be related.  But, Ive got legal workarounds that are allowing me to go forward now.  Cheers,

Comment: The radar has been picked up by Apple and fixed. It is an iOS 8 bug. See https://twitter.com/mairwatching/status/517747734564990976 Here are more details: https://twitter.com/mairwatching/status/517748417452208129

Answer (score -1):

Try using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill and setClipsToBounds:NO

Comment: Still having the same issue :/