# Auto-Layout Issues: iOS 7 vs iOS8

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I am trying to create a collapsible toolbar that works like this (running in iOS 7 -- ugly colors etc. for visualization purposes):

[image: Toolbar behavior in iOS 7]

However, when I run the code in iOS 8, this is what happens:
[image]
I have set up a constraint system that is based on the following:
[image: collapsible toolbar diagram]

A `centering view` (not shown) keeps the toolbar in the screen middle.
A `sizing view` is adjusted to collapse the toolbar. The `sizing view` is anchored to the right of the `centering view`(via a `trailing` constraint).
A `container view` holds the actual content of the toolbar. It is anchored to the right of the `sizing view` (also via a `trailing` constraint).
Various `content views` are contained in the `container view`. They have no constraints. The default constraints applied by the system should be width, height, top, left, which ensures that they keep their relative positions in the `container view`.

The collapsing of the toolbar is achieved as follows:

```
- (IBAction)showLess:(id)sender {
    self.widthConstraint.constant = 50; // adjust this number for collapse / expand
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.centeringView layoutIfNeeded]; // trigger animation
    }];
}
```

Which adjusts the width of the `sizing view`.

**Problem:**
iOS 8 seems to behave as if I had left anchored the content view, but this is not true.

I would sincerely appreciate:

- An explanation as to why iOS 8 would have such a radically different interpretation of the given (reasonably simple) constraints.
- A pointer as to how I can get the intended behavior in iOS 8

[Source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4j7ut7mns5wm6bn/AutoLayoutIssueStackOverFlow.zip?dl=0) available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4j7ut7mns5wm6bn/AutoLayoutIssueStackOverFlow.zip?dl=0) (updated version that works in iOS 8).

**UPDATE:**
The issue was solved with answers from Stack-overflow. Basically, the right answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26066992/228342), but it was nicely summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26070049/228342).
The difference between iOS7 and iOS8 is not in the way the constraints are interpreted, but in the way that update commands are trickled down through the view hierarchy. 
When I implemented the behavior first in iOS 7, I noticed that the animation would only work properly if I called `layoutIfNeeded` on the parent view of the `sizing view` (i.e. on `centering view`). In iOS 7 this apparently  trickled down the view hierarchy automatically. In iOS 8, this is not the case. You have to manually invalidate the view whose constraints have changed with `setNeedsLayout`, and then update the layout with `layoutIfNeeded`. My solution in the updated code looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)showLess:(id)sender {
    self.widthConstraint.constant = 50;
    [self.sizingView setNeedsLayout]; // *** THIS LINE IS NECESSARY TO MAKE THINGS WORK IN iOS 8
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.sizingView layoutIfNeeded]; // trigger animation
    }];
}
```

I hope this helps others who are also stuck on this forward compatibility issue.

Comment: I saw the same thing in one of my apps too.

Comment: Add a normal answer to this question and mark it as the answer. I came here twice thinking it wasn't fixed and then I read the update.

Comment: Also, consider accepting a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was solved with answers from Stack-overflow. Basically, the right answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26066992/228342), but it was nicely summarized in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26070049/228342). The difference between iOS7 and iOS8 is not in the way the constraints are interpreted, but in the way that update commands are trickled down through the view hierarchy. When I implemented the behavior first in iOS 7, I noticed that the animation would only work properly if I called `layoutIfNeeded` on the parent view of the `sizing view` (i.e. on `centering view`). In iOS 7 this apparently trickled down the view hierarchy automatically. In iOS 8, this is **not** the case: You have to manually invalidate the view whose constraints have changed with `setNeedsLayout`, and then update the layout with `layoutIfNeeded`. My solution in the updated code looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)showLess:(id)sender {
    self.widthConstraint.constant = 50;
    [self.sizingView setNeedsLayout]; // *** THIS LINE IS NECESSARY TO MAKE THINGS WORK IN iOS 8
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self.sizingView layoutIfNeeded]; // trigger animation
    }];
}
```

I've updated the question to include the answer, but in response to @unmircea I am posting a separate answer, as well.