# iOS 8: Why is NSLayoutAttributeCenterX failing to center my views? (works in iOS 7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, autolayout

I have some auto layout code that is working in iOS 7, but not in iOS 8. My code has not changed between the two versions.

The situation is that I have a view controller that contains a few subviews that should be stacked vertically like so:

[image: iOS 7 layout]

However, when I run the same code on iOS 8, the following occurs:

[image: iOS 8 layout]

The code that sets up my constraints is as follows:

```
- (void) updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];

    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{
        @"timeLabel": self.timeLabel,
        @"recordingStateImage": self.recordingStateImage,
        @"recordButton": self.recordButton,
        @"spacer1": spacer1,
        @"spacer2": spacer2,
        @"superview": self.view
    };

    if (!portraitConstraints) {
        //
        // Portrait Layout
        //

        portraitConstraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:
            [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[timeLabel][spacer1][recordingStateImage][spacer2(==spacer1)][recordButton(100)]-|"
                                                    options:0
                                                    metrics:0
                                                      views:viewsDictionary]];

        [portraitConstraints addObjectsFromArray:@[
            [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.timeLabel
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                            toItem:self.view
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                        multiplier:1.f
                                          constant:0.f],
            [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.recordingStateImage
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                            toItem:self.view
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                        multiplier:1.f
                                          constant:0.f],
            [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.recordButton
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                            toItem:self.view
                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                        multiplier:1.f
                                          constant:0.f]
        ]];
    }

    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
    [self.view addConstraints:portraitConstraints];

}
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I have examined the workaround noted in the following SO questions:

- [Autolayout problems with iOS8 with code that works fine on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987244/autolayout-problems-with-ios8-with-code-that-works-fine-on-ios7)
- [Issue with Auto Layout on iOS 8 (code works perfectly on iOS 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954831/issue-with-auto-layout-on-ios-8-code-works-perfectly-on-ios-7/26066992#26066992)

but they have not worked (which is calling setNeedsLayout on the subviews instead of the view controller's view).

If anyone has hit issues w/ NSLayoutAttributeCenterX and auto layout on iOS 8, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is your container view here???

Comment: When do you call updateViewConstraints? Is it in a lifecycle method, such as viewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear?

Comment: Do not remove all constraints in updateViewConstraints it will remove constraints which are added by XCode also, and you will never get it back

Comment: I also see logical error that, what if portraitCopnstaints are nill ? in that case you should not remove any constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As my comment help to solve problem and OP need more information about the same issue i post comment as an answer**

---

**Note :**
It's bad practice to remove all constraints as it will remove all constraint added by XCode to fit your view properly in device.

**Having different UI in landscape and portrait mode**
 
If your view having different constraint in landscape and portrait (In compact and regular view).
you can use size classes [introduce in XCode6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014509-SW15) with [backward comparability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1).

Please follow this [blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial) explaining size class very nicely.
[download project](http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/AdaptiveWeather.zip) create in above blog.

**Output:**
View in landscape mode
[image]

View in portrait mode:
[image]

Comment: jw - do you have any thoughts on making this stuff backwards compatible? What I ended up doing was keep my old logic in ```updateConstraints```, but only run it when the OS is < iOS 8.

Comment: according to apple size clasess are backward compatible https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/DeployingSizeClassesonEarlieriOSVersions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH13-SW1

Comment: I did not try but this question my help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172860/how-can-xcode-6-adaptive-uis-be-backwards-compatible-with-ios-7-and-ios-6

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that iOS 8 and Xcode 6 adds extra constraints to the view to help lay out its elements. I figured this out by [Jageen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285606/ios-8-why-is-nslayoutattributecenterx-failing-to-center-my-views-works-in-ios?noredirect=1#comment43046105_27285606) above and in a [comment on a github issue](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry/issues/106#issuecomment-57207117).

The solution to the problem is to not call `[self.view removeConstraints]` in iOS 8 as it will remove these extra, required constraints. My personal workaround to this is to utilize nibs for iOS 8 w/ its orientation-specific constraints and do an OS check to only run the above code in versions <= to iOS 7.

If anyone has a backwards-compatible workaround to this issue w/ calling `removeConstraints` on a view, I would be very interested in seeing it (as I have a different layout for portrait vs. landscape).

Comment: As you have different layout for portrait and landscape you can use size class (introduce in XCode6 with backward comparability), have look at this example http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. In my case its cause was the line

> self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
>   (self is UIViewController)

After setting the constraint I typed po self.view.layer during a breakpoint into the console and it appeared fine. I was setting the constraint in viewDidLoad (experimenting with viewWillAppear and viewWillLayoutSubviews yields the same result). However, when I added a breakpoint in viewDidAppear and typed the same command in the console the width and height of self.view had both changed to zero. I removed the above line and it worked. self.view retained its height and width and the subview aligned in the center.